# Background Voice recording in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

Researched a lot for Solution for recording voice in Background (When another app is running/ when phone is locked, etc).
Searched whole MSDN, stackoverflow for any solution regarding this, Still didn't find it.

Also checked the Api references, they say MediaCapture wont work in background.

But I found two apps, which can record in background. As reverse engineering is not possible with encrypted app, I can't check how did they achieve it.

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/pocket-recorder/eda4e045-733f-e011-854c-00237de2db9e
http://www.windowsphone.com/en-in/store/app/voice-recorder-8-1/511c6375-8bf3-4d19-8248-1650a60ea1ae

I checked whether they use Voip Capabilities, but it is not listed. So there is some other work around, But don't know how!. These apps are paid, so I wish to help community with free solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this with background tasks. This is because if your app has a lock on the microphone, you won't be able to perform certain functions with your phone (i.e. phone calls)

Comment: I would suggest, if you have windows phone, for checking those 2 apps, i posted in question, It works in background!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Voice Recorder can record voice at the background by stopping every audio files and listening from the phone mic. Even if you switch the screen off, or the screen shut off, the under dog software will still be very active and recording the least sounds it hears and very powerfully clear. Now, I am very surprised to find a software that broke the feats of windows phone, although the software can not allow you to copy the recorded file to sd card or to the phone memory unless a paid version. This is good all the same.